# Using wildcard subdomains with wildcard SSL on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain, cname

We have an app recently deployed to Heroku. I think we have hit the wall in terms of our requirements (please make my conclusion wrong ) .

It's a project management app. Management has decided to go for all SSL solution hence we got ourselves wildcard certificate ( *.ourapp.net) from GoDaddy which we added successfully to Heroku under Hostname based SSL. Hostname based SSL requires putting particular CNAME(which needs to be secured) pointed to AmazonAWS url which is given by Heroku. For example , if we wanted to secure var.ourapp.net we will have to point CNAME var.ourapp.net ----> appid42352herokucom-324234.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com [this is example URL)

Since we wanted every first-level subdomain to be secure, we had to put *.myapp.net CNAME pointed to AmazonURL.

But this interferes with our application design where every wildcard subdomain(basic and wildcard domains are already added to the app) needs to be processed such that each customer could get branded URL like customername.outapp.net

Currently DNS is handled by Zerigo tier one.

Please suggest/recommend

Comment: not sure I understand the question. Can you expand the scenarios - perhaps with real domains to clear things up?

Comment: I having something similar but a different issue. How were you able to create a wildcard CNAME? Is it supported by zerigo tier 1? (currently on godaddy)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it should work.

You added a CNAME record:
`*.ourapp.com` to `appid42352herokucom-324234.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

User requests `https://ACLIENT.ourapp.com`. Browser follows CNAME, connects to 
`appid42352herokucom-324234.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com` on port 503. The server responds with your certificate. It then passes the request to Heroku's "routing mesh". It gets a request to `https://ACLIENT.ourapp.com`, looks up the hostname in heroku domain configuration and finds a wildcard domain for the app. It then passes the request to the application.